# Django CMS 3.1.3, Python 3.4 and Django 1.8 CustomUser

Tags: django, django-cms

I have found similar post but none of the answers helped me.  I'm getting a "LookupError: Model 'email_user.EmailUser' not registered." when trying to run a makemigrations or migrate.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**ProjectStructure**

```
ProjectRoot/
 - email_user/
    --  __init__.py
    -- admin.py
    -- models.py 
 - djangocms/
    -- static/
    -- templates/
    -- __init__.py
    -- urls.py
 - manage.py
 - settings.py
 - wsgi.py
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'email_user',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'treebeard',
    'djangocms_style',
    'djangocms_column',
    'djangocms_file',
    'djangocms_flash',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'djangocms_inherit',
    'djangocms_link',
    'djangocms_picture',
    'djangocms_teaser',
    'djangocms_video',
    'reversion',
    'djangocms',
) 

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "email_user.EmailUser"
```

**email_user/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from email_user.models import EmailUser

admin.site.register(EmailUser)
```

**email_user/models.py**

```
class EmailUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField('email address', max_length=255, unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh,

After hours of digging around I tracked down the problem.  The Django CMS Installer will automatically setup the settings.py file for you and the INSTALLED_APPS area.

So for some reason some of the dependencies are not setup correctly and following the documentation will result in hours of banging your head on the table.

The Installed apps should look like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'djangocms_admin_style',  # MOVED THIS HERE
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'email_user',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor', # MOVED THIS HERE
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'treebeard',
    'djangocms_style',
    'djangocms_column',
    'djangocms_file',
    'djangocms_flash',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'djangocms_inherit',
    'djangocms_link',
    'djangocms_picture',
    'djangocms_teaser',
    'djangocms_video',
    'reversion',
    'securepal',
)
```

Hopefully this might save someone from having to track this down

Comment: `djangocms_admin_style` should be fine on top of the application list.
`djangocms_text_ckeditor` can be safely moved down. I'll change the installer accordingly